# Ejecutar un Procedimiento almacenado con SQL Dinamico SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

queria pedirles su ayuda para saber como puedo ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado con sql dinamico ya que estoy intentando lo siguiente pero no me funciona me marca este error:

> (3 rows affected)
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 59 Must declare the
> scalar variable "@cur_clave_str".

Y este es mi codigo:

```
DECLARE  @cur_clave_str varchar(250) = 'MX2020,GDL2023'
DECLARE @tblVar dbo.EmpClaveListV2
insert into @tblVar  values ('1042793'), ('973386'), ('4073455')
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQL = N'
EXEC dbo.Report_201873 @DateStart =''2023-03-01'',   @DateEnd= ''2023-04-14'',  @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
 @EmpData = @tblVar
'
EXEC [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp]..sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL
```

Comment: Personalmente creo que ya llevas un tiempo por aquí, y deberías de molestarte y  [crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Lo que has "tirado" en la pregunta, a primera vista, no tiene sentido. ¿Porque usar un procedimiento dinámico, cuando puedes llamarlo estático?

Comment: El error parece, además, muy claro. No has declarado la variable @cur_clave_str

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar el error podrías especificar el parámetro `@cur_clave_str` en la llamada a `sp_executesqlLo`. Y agregar la declaración de las variables `@cur_clave_str` y `@tblVar` dentro del bloque de código dinámico.

```
DECLARE @cur_clave_str varchar(250) = 'MX2020,GDL2023'
DECLARE @tblVar dbo.EmpClaveListV2
INSERT INTO @tblVar VALUES ('1042793'), ('973386'), ('4073455')
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @SQL = N'
DECLARE @cur_clave_str varchar(250) = @cur_clave_str
DECLARE @tblVar dbo.EmpClaveListV2
INSERT INTO @tblVar VALUES (''1042793''), (''973386''), (''4073455'')

EXEC dbo.Report_201873 
    @DateStart = ''2023-03-01'',
    @DateEnd = ''2023-04-14'',
    @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
    @EmpData = @tblVar
'
EXEC [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp]..sp_executesql @stmt = @SQL, N'@cur_clave_str varchar(250)', @cur_clave_str
```